# Reading a web based datafile every five minutes with MS Access

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a local webbased datafile that I would like to query every five minutes and save the data in a table.  The data is a flat file that I would need to parse if it just went into a table.   I am fam. with VBA and have a copy of some visual studio code but MS Access does not seem to have some of the functions of Visual Studio

Comment: You can use SSIS to read the file in and insert into the MS Access DB.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Access VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) to update an Access database. In fact, in this case a better approach would be to create a little VB.NET (or C#) console application to retrieve the data file and update the Access database via `System.Data.OleDb` or `System.Data.Odbc`. You could use the Task Scheduler in Windows to run your .NET application every five minutes (or as often as necessary).